# Resource for Learning jQuery

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know of a really good resource to learn jQuery? I really want to learn in order to add animation to my website. I want a good all inclusive course, videos would be nice, and I will pay for it.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Tryout [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)

Comment: I learned it from the ebook jQuery Compressed https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B006DI6QJ2/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be available any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W3 schools has learning courses for several programming languages and tools.

jQuery course is very well-designed in this site:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Also Codecademy has introduced free jQuery course, with exercises that forces you to solve them! I learned jQuery here:

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend SoloLearn, there are free courses on there for multiple different languages. The mobile app is really nice and works very well.

When you complete a course you get an online certificate, not that they'll mean much considering how easy they are to get, it's still nice to have.